# Generate OAuth signature in Java

Tags: java, oauth

I'm working on java web application and now I'm trying to connect my website with [QTIWorks](https://webapps.ph.ed.ac.uk/qtiworks/)

I have a consumer key and secret, I need to generate OAuth signature to connect with QTIWorks through LTI

```
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>
<form action="https://webapps.ph.ed.ac.uk/qtiworks-dev2/lti/domainlaunch" name="ltiLaunchForm" id="ltiLaunchForm" method="post" target="basicltiLaunchFrame" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" style="display: block;">
   <input type="hidden" name="context_id" value="cid-00113">
   <input type="hidden" name="context_label" value="SI106">
   <input type="hidden" name="context_title" value="Design of Personal Environments 1">
   <input type="hidden" name="ext_note" value="Instructor from first course">
   <input type="hidden" name="launch_presentation_locale" value="en_us">
   <input type="hidden" name="lis_person_contact_email_primary" value="sian@imscert.org">
   <input type="hidden" name="lis_person_name_family" value="Instructor">
   <input type="hidden" name="lis_person_name_given" value="Siân">
   <input type="hidden" name="lis_person_sourcedid" value="school.edu:user">
   <input type="hidden" name="resource_link_description" value="This learning space is private">
   <input type="hidden" name="resource_link_id" value="res-0012612">
   <input type="hidden" name="resource_link_title" value="My Weekly Wiki">
   <input type="hidden" name="roles" value="Instructor">
   <input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_info_product_family_code" value="sakai-unit">
   <input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_info_version" value="0.9">
   <input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_description" value="University of School (LMSng)">
   <input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_guid" value="lmsng.school.edu">
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="user-0016">
   <input type="hidden" name="oauth_callback" value="about:blank">
   <input type="hidden" name="lis_outcome_service_url" value="....">
   <input type="hidden" name="lis_result_sourcedid" value="{&quot;zap&quot; : &quot;Siân JSON 1234 Sourcedid <>&amp;lt;&quot;}">
   <input type="hidden" name="custom_simple_key" value="custom_simple_value">
   <input type="hidden" name="custom_complex____________key" value="Complex!@#$^*(){}[]½Value">
   <input type="hidden" name="lti_version" value="LTI-1p0">
   <input type="hidden" name="lti_message_type" value="basic-lti-launch-request">
   <input type="submit" name="ext_submit" value="Finish Launch">
   <input type="hidden" name="oauth_version" value="1.0">
   <input type="hidden" name="oauth_nonce" value="505005bff1c2cf2e1750ed914e489a9b">
   <input type="hidden" name="oauth_timestamp" value="1427022367">
   <input type="hidden" name="oauth_consumer_key" value="my consumer key">
   <input type="hidden" name="oauth_signature_method" value="HMAC-SHA1">
   <input type="hidden" name="oauth_signature" value="I need generate this value">
   <input type="hidden" name="ext_submit" value="Finish Launch">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form>


<iframe name="basicltiLaunchFrame" id="basicltiLaunchFrame" src="" width="100%" height="900" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1" transparency="">

</iframe>
</body>
```

I need to generate OAuth signature at this line

```
<input type="hidden" name="oauth_signature" value="I need generate this value">
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do it with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("oauth_signature").value = "Value you want to generate";
```

Edit:

You can use a library for cryptographic algorithms (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) to calculate the oauth signature:

```
var key = document.getElementById("oauth_consumer_key").value
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(key);
document.getElementById("oauth_signature").value = hash
```

Depending on the value of *oauth_signature_method* you should use the appropriate cryptographic algorithm.

```
switch(document.getElementById("oauth_signature_method").value) {
    case "HMAC-SHA1":
        var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(key)
        break;
    case "HMAC-SHA-2":
        var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(key)
        break;
    case ...
}
```

Comment: This is actually not quite correct.  It is not as simple as just running SHA-1 - you need to compute a base string based on all of the properties on the pose *and* the URL being posted to, add the key and secret, compute the signature, and then add the signature to the post data.  LTI 1.x uses OAuth 1.0a https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849 for its signing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sakai LTI code (Open Source Apache) to do the signature.  I have extracted the portable bits of the Sakai LTI implementation at:

https://github.com/tsugiproject/tsugi-util

The artifact is even in Sonatype so you can add it to your maven configuration - documentation is in the README in github.  What you are looking for is two methods:

- `signProperties` Adds the oauth fields and a signature
- `postLaunchHTML` Generates the HTML form and auto-submits it

https://github.com/tsugiproject/tsugi-util/blob/master/src/java/org/tsugi/basiclti/BasicLTIUtil.java

The methods have a lot of parameters but this way they are very independent from any storage or other aspects of your Java application.